# visual studio 2015 node js app doesn't start debugging

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015

I am creating a purely server side nodejs app in visual studio and the majority of times I go to debug it, it does not start running my javascript.

I see "Debugger listening on port xxxx" and nothing else.

Opening and closing the project solves it and have had some luck manually ending the VSHub.exe process (maybe coincidental) but I don't want to have to do this everytime I debug.

Anyone seeing this or got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/466) with the node js tools extension.

The fix was included in dev build v1.1.Dev-9.17.2015 which is available from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/releases) until it is included in an official release.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the Community version, deleting the project, reinstalling VS2015, then recreating the project seems to have fixed it.

Mysterious.